# JQuery doesn't replacing background image

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a `background image` on the header section of my blog. I use a conditional php rule to check if the category is a podcast, `make x`. That work's, but the script to change the background image inside didn't work.

```php
if ( in_category( 14 ) ) : ?>
    <script>
        $('.page-title-section')
           .css({ "background-image": "https://miradasocial.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/miradas-transp-largo-x3-300x115.png"});
    </script>
<?php endif;
```

I  tried with !important on the atribute and with  `$('.bg-secondary')` too, but this didn't work.

**HTML Structure**

```html
<section class="page-title-section bg-secondary" 
  style="background-image: url('https://miradasocial.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/entrevista-terraza.jpg')">
```

You can see live example [here](https://miradasocial.es/category/podcasts/).

The returned console error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library?

Comment: it seems that you didn't added jQuery library

Comment: Missing the `url()` part. jQuery won't wrap the url string with it, you need to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for Jquery if you're using PHP (laravel or anything)
you can set you credential directly with PHP

```
<?php $pageTitleBgImage = in_category( 14 )
  ? "https://miradasocial.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/miradas-transp-largo-x3-300x115.png"
  : "https://miradasocial.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/entrevista-terraza.jpg";
?>
<section 
  class="page-title-section bg-secondary" 
  style="background-image: url('<?php echo $pageTitleBgImage; ?>' )"> 

</section>
```